# How does the output come about from this C code?

Tags: c, output

This was a question from a previous exam, and I cannot seem to figure out how we get the output from this code. I understand how to get the 5, but seem to find difficulty solving for the next two digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST(x,y) x + y*y
#define SECOND(p,q) printf("%" #p "\n", q)

int main(void) {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    printf("%d", FIRST(a,b));
    printf("%d", FIRST(a,b+1));
    SECOND(d,a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
561
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the program?  There are three single-digit print operations.  The macro `FIRST` doesn't parenthesize the arguments in the expansion, so it behaves weirdly.  The `d` in the invocation of SECOND is used as a format, not a variable.  You could use `i` in place of the `d`.

Comment: `FIRST(a,b+1)` expands to `a + b+1*b+1`, which will evaluate to 6. `SECOND(d,a)` expands to `printf("%d\n", a)`, which will print 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%d", FIRST(a,b));`: `FIRST(a,b)` expands to `a + b*b`. When evaluated, 1 + 2*2 = 5. This prints 5.

`printf("%d", FIRST(a,b+1));`: `FIRST(a,b+1)` expands to `a + b+1*b+1`. When evaluated, 1 + 2+1*2+1 = 6. This prints 6.

`SECOND(d,a);` expands to `printf("%" "d" "\n", a);`<sup>1</sup> This prints 1 and the newline.

<sup>1</sup> The `#p` in the macro means "literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant". See [Stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing).

Answer (score 1):

2. The value does not get evaluated first when it is "substituted" into the macro.

   i.e. printf("%d", a + b + 1 * b + 1);
3. This one is more straightforward, it replaces the parameter p to the string literal.

   i.e. printf("%d\n", a);